# Webpack Unknown option '--display-error-details'

Tags: webpack, webpack-cli

I am in the process of upgrading webpack from v4 to v5.

I have started with upgrading webpack-cli, as explained in the [doc](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/).

So when I run `npx webpack --version` I get

```
webpack 4.46.0
webpack-cli 4.5.0
```

Now I try to run the following command : `npx webpack --display-error-details`.
The [documentation](https://v4.webpack.js.org/api/cli/#debug-options) of the webpack cli for v4 says this option is available.

But I get `Error: Unknown option '--display-error-details'`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I know that from the `webpack-cli` `^4.x` (which works with `webpack` `v5`) this option is deprecated which means this option is only available at lower version such as `^3.x` version.

So in order to work with `^4.x`, you might check all the available options [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#debug-options) to find what you need or you can `npx webpack --help`.

Answer (score 12):

For the version 5.x of webpack you have to specify **stats.errorDetails** to true at the webpack config, like follows:

```js
const customConfig = {
   stats: {
      errorDetails: true,
      children: true
   },
}
```